# Microsoft sync The default schema does not exist

Tags: c#, microsoft-sync-framework

I use Microsoft sync framework to sync data between remote and local data base, but I face Error
**"The default schema does not exist"** when applying provisioning on the remote server.

SqlSyncProvider sqlProviderLocal = new SqlSyncProvider(scopeName, sqlConnLocal);
                SqlSyncProvider sqlProviderRemote = new SqlSyncProvider(scopeName, sqlConnRemote);

```
            SqlSyncScopeProvisioning scopeProvisionLocal = new SqlSyncScopeProvisioning(sqlConnLocal);
            scopeProvisionLocal.ObjectSchema = ".dbo";
            if (!scopeProvisionLocal.ScopeExists(scopeName))
            {
                DbSyncScopeDescription scopeDesc = new DbSyncScopeDescription(scopeName);

                foreach (var item in Tables)
                {
                    scopeDesc.Tables.Add(SqlSyncDescriptionBuilder.GetDescriptionForTable(item, sqlConnLocal));
                }

                scopeProvisionLocal.PopulateFromScopeDescription(scopeDesc);
                scopeProvisionLocal.SetCreateTableDefault(DbSyncCreationOption.Skip);
                scopeProvisionLocal.Apply();
            }

            SqlSyncScopeProvisioning scopeProvisionRemote = new SqlSyncScopeProvisioning(sqlConnRemote);
            scopeProvisionRemote.ObjectSchema = ".dbo"; 
            if (!scopeProvisionRemote.ScopeExists(scopeName))
            {
                DbSyncScopeDescription scopeDesc = SqlSyncDescriptionBuilder.GetDescriptionForScope(scopeName, sqlConnLocal);
                scopeProvisionRemote.PopulateFromScopeDescription(scopeDesc);
                scopeProvisionRemote.Apply();
            }

            agent.LocalProvider = sqlProviderLocal;
            agent.RemoteProvider = sqlProviderRemote;
            SyncOperationStatistics stats = agent.Synchronize();

            result = ClearExtras();

            sqlConnLocal.Close();
            sqlConnRemote.Close();
```

Comment: Are you sure you should be setting the schemea to ".dbo" rather than "dbo".

Comment: raising the same error ether setting it "dbo" or ".dbo"

Comment: schema should be without period.e.g., "dbo". unless the account you use to provision has a different default schema, you dont even have to specify dbo. can you pose the actual stack trace of the error? also,when you specify a schema during provisioning, you should specify the same when synching.